# Google chrome is slow on refreshing localhost website

Tags: google-chrome, localhost

I have a local website running on nodejs simple server made by gulp-connect plugin.

When i refresh that local address, in Internet Explorer 11 it takes only `2s` but in chrome it's versy slow. usually `9s` and sometimes `5s` or even `40s`.

Most of this time is on `Waiting for localhost...` and loading actual website only takes `2s`; There is no external resource in codes, all fonts and files are in my computer; CPU, RAM and HD usages are normal.

I also tried to open in `new incognito window`, disabling plugins, disabling `predict network actions`, using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and removing cache files.

**EDIT:**

In devtools > network tab, requirejs file waits about `6s`; WHY? Maybe you know! This is a screenshot of network tab: [image: network tab]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because i used watch in nodejs server and number of files that were under watch was very much, server was under impact and in fact server was slow, not chrome.

I reduced number of files under watch for livereload and everything is normal now!